# YARN + how to identify what YARN mode is using from cli Capacity Scheduler or Fair Scheduler

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari, hdp

before asking my question I Just want to give the diff between YARN that use Fair Scheduler or Capacity Scheduler

Fair Scheduler
Fair scheduling is a method of assigning resources to jobs such that all jobs get, on average, an equal share of resources over time. When there is a single job running, that job uses the entire cluster. When other jobs are submitted, tasks slots that free up are assigned to the new jobs, so that each job gets roughly the same amount of CPU time.

Capacity Scheduler
The Capacity Scheduler is designed to allow sharing a large cluster while giving each organization a minimum capacity guarantee. The central idea is that the available resources in the Hadoop cluster are partitioned among multiple organizations who collectively fund the cluster based on computing needs. There is an added benefit that an organization can access any excess capacity
no being used by others. This provides elasticity for the organizations in a cost-effective manner.

additional to above , we have HDP cluster with YARN resource manager service and 34 node-managers
all services are view from Ambari dashboard

all machines are installed on Linux 7.2

is it possible to verify from yarn cli or other Hadoop approach what YARN is choosing ?  **Fair Scheduler**  or **Capacity Scheduler**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in shell:

```
./path-to-your-hadoop/bin/hdfs getconf -confKey yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class
```

Result for Fair Scheduler

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler

Result for Capacity Scheduler

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler